# DRF - request.user returns AnonymousUser in APIView while logged in during api call from fetch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I've constructed a APIView as such:

```
class CustomAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user or not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Response("User not logged in", status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    # Other stuff
```

And in my html template I'm making a call to it using fetchAPI:

```
 fetch('/api/request/url/', {method: 'get'})
            .then(
             // Process info );
```

I'm logged in through all this, but I'm always being greeted with a 403 response with the request.user variable in the APIView returning AnonymousUser. However, if I try and visit the api url manually everything works out right.

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your authentication mechanism ? is it Token based authentication or Session Authentication ? can you put your setting DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES here .. the problem with fetch is that it will not send cookies to the server, resulting failure on cookie based authentications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with fetch api is that by defualt it will not send cookies to the server.

> By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server,
>   resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on
>   maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init
>   option must be set).

So You have to set credentials: 'same-origin' in your fetch request,

```
fetch('/api/request/url/', {method: "GET", credentials: 'same-origin'})
            .then(
             // Process info );
```

for cross-origin requests, use `credentials: 'include'`